# Cypress selectFile does not work for .wav files

Tags: javascript, html, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I am writing a Cypress test to check if uploaded `.mp3` and `.wav` files correctly show up in the UI. I am using the [selectFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile#Syntax) api to simulate uploading files to the browser.

In the test below, the `.mp3` test passes, but the `.wav` test fails at `.contains` because the `.wav` file is not found in the UI after `selectFile` runs.

```
  context('Upload tos UI', () => {
    it('upload audio.mp3', () => {
      cy.getByTestId('upload-button').eq(0).selectFile('cypress/fixtures/audio.mp3', { force: true });
      cy.getByTestId('uploaded-file-list').contains('audio.mp3');
    });
    it('upload audio.wav', () => {
      cy.getByTestId('upload-button').eq(0).selectFile('cypress/fixtures/audio.wav', { force: true });
      cy.getByTestId('uploaded-file-list').contains('audio.wav');
    });
  });
```

There is an open [github issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/21240) about how when a `.wav` file is uploaded using `selectFile()`, the `file.type` attached to the file is '`audio/wave'` when the correct type is `'audio/wav'`.

Is this cypress issue the reason for why my `.wav` test fails? Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mimeType was the issue. To resolve it, add the correct `'audio/wav'` mimeType like so

```
cy.getByTestId('upload-button').eq(0).selectFile({ contents: 'cypress/fixtures/audio.wav', mimeType: 'audio/wav' }, { force: true });
```